# SVP Vapoursynth configure: error: C++11 support required

Tags: linux-mint

I was trying to install SVP (SmoothVideo Project) on my Linux Mint 19.1, but I ran into one problem. When I follow the instructions here: https://www.svp-team.com/wiki/SVP:Linux and the part "Building 3rd-party apps from sources -> Vapoursynth -> ./configure" I get the error which I have written on the topic. I tried searching for an answer but I found none regarding this issue. It also lists these before the error occurs:

```
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++14... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++11... no
```

Comment: Your system doesn't appear to have either `gcc` or `g++` (or equivalent C/C++ compilers) installed

Comment: I seemed to already have gcc installed, but not g++. I installed g++ with this command: 'apt update && apt install build-essential g++' and after that it worked. Thanks!